# Detach and take a copy database and attach it to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to copy a database file using file management concept in vb.

My code is:

```
IO.File.Copy(MukilCommon.APP_PATH & "\" & CurrentDbName & ".mdf", MukilCommon.APP_PATH & "\" & CurrentDbName & "_" & yearStr & ".mdf")
IO.File.Copy(MukilCommon.APP_PATH & "\" & CurrentDbName & ".ldf", MukilCommon.APP_PATH & "\" & CurrentDbName & "_" & yearStr & ".ldf")
```

My code is copied a database from new database on `e:`, like this:

```
 sample.mdf
 sample.ldf
 sample_2016.mdf
 sample_2016.ldf
```

I used this code for attach my copied database in SQL Server.

```
  db1.Execute("EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = '" & CurrentDbName & "_" & yearStr & "', @filename1 = '" & MukilCommon.APP_PATH & "\" & CurrentDbName & "_" & yearStr & ".mdf', @filename2 = '" & MukilCommon.APP_PATH & "\" & CurrentDbName & "_" & yearStr & ".ldf'")
```

But I get this message.

> Can't attach a file name, "sample" database is already exists in SQL Server.

Actually the copied file has try to attached on original database. How to I attach this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions:
Put the files in different folders, you have to keep mdf and ldf files with the same name, use this script:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Simple_2017] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\2017\Simple.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\2017\Simple_log.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

don't use sp_attach_db

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand, you have data and log files of a detached database and you want to attach this database on a SQL Server instance.

From the error, I understand that there is already a database named "sample" on your SQL Server instance

So, if you want to attach a new database, you can choose a new name for your database to attach. Maybe you can call it sample2

Since you have already tried to detach, I could guess your data files are in a seperate folder than the existing sample database files exist
You can keep these files on seperate folders, so you can use the same fille names for example TestDB.mdf for both sample database and sample2 database

Then you can execute your code like

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'sample2', 
    @filename1 = 
N'C:\NewDataFolder\TestDB.mdf', 
    @filename2 = 
N'C:\NewDataFolder\TestDB_log.ldf';
```

Comment: As u said, first change the location for my copied database in my local pc , then i attach it on my sql server.

Comment: Did you try to change the database name?